# Variable length padding in scapy

Tags: python, python-2.7, protocols, scapy

Basically I want to be able to build my protocol using the below class and if the layer is not byte-aligned, add padding to make it byte-aligned.

Generic example:

```
class Test(Packet):
fields_desc = [ BitField("field1", 0, 2),
                BitField("field2", 0, 2),
                ConditionalField(BitField("field3", 0, 1), lambda pkt:pkt.field1 == 1),
                <variable_length_bitfield_padding>, ]
```

I want the above example to be able to build, any suggestions would be appreciated.

My current workaround is:

```
class Test(Packet):
fields_desc = [ BitField("field1", 0, 2),
                BitField("field2", 0, 2),
                ConditionalField(BitField("field3", 0, 1), lambda pkt:pkt.field1 == 1),
                ConditionalField(BitField("padAlign", 0, 3), lambda pkt:pkt.field1 == 1)),
                ConditionalField(BitField("padAlign", 0, 4), lambda pkt:pkt.field1 == 0)),]
```

This isn't a great workaround because the protocol will get more complex and consist of many more "ConditionalField"s.

PadField is not really what I'm looking for (I don't think), more of a PadLayer: padAlign = len(layer)%8

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `PadField`

```
help(PadField)
Help on class PadField in module scapy.fields:

class PadField(builtins.object)
 |  Add bytes after the proxified field so that it ends at the specified
 |  alignment from its beginning
 |
```

It will pad a specific field, such as

```
fields_desc = [ BitField("field1", 0, 2),
                BitField("field2", 0, 2),
                PadField(
                    ConditionalField(BitField("field3", 0, 1), lambda pkt:pkt.field1 == 1),
                    1
                )
]
```

Comment: thanks for the share, but that isn't exactly what I was striving for, I have updated my question to hopefully be a bit more clear.

Comment: Wait so you are not doing a Byte alignement (byte=8bits), but instead a 4-bits alignment right ?

Comment: So the layer (packet) will be byte aligned (divisible by 8bits w/padding) but the fields within are not aligned at all.  (fields can be any width: 17bits, 19bits, etc.). Maybe there is a way to do it in one of scapy's "build" functions?

Comment: You may want to use a FlagsField of a length of 4 instead :/

Answer (score 0):

Ran into similar problem. Scapy was not happy with custom packets that are not byte aligned. Also my incoming raw data was padded. Here is solution that I came up with.
Double check this works on your protocol. Specifically bit shifting might be different.
Just use `PaddedPacket` class as a base class instead of original `Packet`.

```
import bitstring
from scapy.all import Packet


class PaddedPacket(Packet):
    def pre_dissect(self, s):
        """ Pre dissect will fix padding problems for payload layer """
        if type(s) is tuple:
            s = bitstring.BitArray(bytes=s[0]) << s[1]
            s = s.bytes

        return s

    def extract_padding(self, s):
        """
        Extract current layer's padding.

        :param str s: the current layer
        :return: a couple of strings (actual layer, padding)
        """
        if type(s) is tuple:
            # Reconstruct padding
            pad = bitstring.BitArray(bytes=s[0]) << s[1]
            pad = pad.bytes
            return None, pad

        else:
            return s, None
```